# What format are Firefox Marketplace apps in, and where are they installed under desktop Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I got Firefox 35, and noticed there is an Apps thing, so I decided to check it out:

[image: firefox_01.png]

This takes me to Firefox Marketplace, where I choose to try a game by clicking "Free", and I am prompted if I want to "Install":

[image: firefox_02.png]

I click on "Install", and I get "Installation in progress":

[image: firefox_03.png]

... which concludes with "Application installed":

[image: firefox_04.png]

My questions are:

- What sort of files/formats does Firefox use for these games; are the games distributed as executables, or does Firefox run them?
- Where are the files of this application installed, locally on my desktop filesystem?
- Since there is no "Uninstall"/"Remove" button - how do I uninstall these games, should I happen to install one?

Comment: Related (but doesn't answer this): [14.04 - How to uninstall apps installed through Firefox Marketplace? - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/574835/how-to-uninstall-apps-installed-through-firefox-marketplace)

Answer (score 0):

I have been investigating this myself. From what I can tell:

- There is a .exe file downloaded along with supporting files.
- The applications seem to be downloaded to an appropriatly named folder within you AppData\Roaming folder.
- You can uninstall the app similar to any other program: Control Panel -> Programs and Features. This appears to remove the .exe and most of the supporting files but leaves the profile information.